# What are the advantages of using "{}" for casting in C Language?

Tags: c++, c, literals, function-call, compound-literals

I am trying to understand why use this casting style in ProcessHacker Code.

```
 RtlSetHeapInformation(
            PhHeapHandle,
            HeapCompatibilityInformation,
            &(ULONG){ HEAP_COMPATIBILITY_LFH }, // HEAP_COMPATIBILITY_LFH = 2UL 
            sizeof(ULONG)
            );
```

What are the advantages of using "{}" for casting? Does it work in C and C++?

```
&(ULONG){ HEAP_COMPATIBILITY_LFH }, // HEAP_COMPATIBILITY_LFH = 2UL
```

Comment: Simplifies macros. You can the same scheme for scalar types and structs. Both 'int x=5;' and 'int x ={5};' are the same thing

Comment: why do you tag C++ here?

Comment: @phuclv the question asks if it is valid for c++

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This

```
&(ULONG){ HEAP_COMPATIBILITY_LFH },
```

is not a casting. It is a compound literal. It creates an object of the type `ULONG` with automatic storage duration and initializes it with the value `HEAP_COMPATIBILITY_LFH`. Then the address of the object is taken.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned long *p = &( unsigned long ){ 10ul };
    
    printf( "%lu\n", *p );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10
```

From the C Standard (6.5.2.5 Compound literals)

> 3 A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name
> followed by a brace enclosed list of initializers is a compound
> literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the
> initializer list.

You may imagine the definition of the compound literal the following way.

For example you may initialize a scalar variable using a braced list like

```
unsigned long x = { 10ul };
```

But a compound literal has no name. So this construction

```
( unsigned long ){ 10ul }
```

in fact looks like

```
unsigned long unnamed_literal = { 10ul };
     ^                             ^
     |                             | 
( unsigned long )               { 10ul }
```

Pay attention to that in C++ there is no such a notion as the compound literal.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is not valid in C++

Comment: oh! I got it! Thank you~

Answer (score 6):

`(ULONG){ HEAP_COMPATIBILITY_LFH }` in C is object literal initialization.

It essentially creates an anonymous automatic (`auto`, on the stack) or static (if used in a filescope compound literal) and initializes it.

`(TYPE){ InitVal }` is essentially equivalent to `TYPE __someInternalNameXYZ = { InitVal } /*lifted above the expression where used*/; __someInternalNameXYZ /*use*/` and it differs from casting in serveral ways.

1. *Casting* only works on scalars (pointers and numbers), whereas *compound literals* work with any type
2. *Casting* produces *rvalues* (can't take their address) whereas *compound literals* are *lvalues* (can use unary `&` on them).
3. *Casting* is big hammer: it will happily reinterpret pointers as numbers or vice versa whereas *compound literal* initialization is more gentle as it abides by the stricter rules for initialization/assignment ([https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1))
4. *Casting* will produce integer constant expression (usable in `switch` `case`s, bitfield widths or array sizes) if the casted value was an integer constant to start with but compound literal initialization never does.

Compound literals are a C99 feature. They don't exist in C++ AFAIK.

In C, you can sometimes use compound literal initialization to get the gentler converting effect of C++'s `static_cast`.

Comment: Compound literals were introduced by [C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.5). They're certainly a C11 feature :-)