# Why is an explicit cast necessary in the following struct definition

Tags: c, struct, initialization, literals, compound-literals

With `struct` initialization via a compound literal, it will do the casting itself. For example:

```
struct movie {
    char title[50];
    int year;
};
typedef struct movie Item;

typedef struct node {
    Item        item;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct linkedlist {
    Node   *head;
    size_t size;
} LinkedList;
```

```
LinkedList movies2 = {
    .head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
    .size=1
};
```

However, if I separate the definition, I have to add in an explicit cast:

```
LinkedList movies2;
movies2 = (LinkedList) {
    .head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
    .size=1
};
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/dG8nMh

And if I leave out the `(cast_type)` in the second one I will get an error along the lines of  `error: expected expression before ‘{’ token`. Why is this so?

That is, why does the initialization not need the cast but the other definition does? My thought was the second version should be able to resolve itself without the explicit cast but obviously that is incorrect.

Comment: It would help to show the definition for these things.

Comment: I think this is undefined behaviour. You're using the address of a temporary that gets trashed as soon as it falls out of scope. A cast is "necessary" because by default it doesn't want to work.

Comment: That you could be assigning an array to struct variable type?

Comment: @tadman: these constructs are called [compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)

Comment: @pmg Yeah, I know, but I think in this case it's not going to work. What's the lifetime of that inner literal?

Comment: @tadman updated with the structs.

Comment: The assignment creates a copy (even if the lifetime was to next sequence point it would be ok).

Comment: Normally you'd create this in one shot with the properties spelled out immediately, not as a two-stage thing. This involves an unnecessary copy.

Comment: @pmg I mean specifically the embedded `.head` assignment in that.

Comment: `(LinkedList) {}` is not a cast. It is a syntax for compound literals, which you seem to be aware of.

Comment: [C11 6.5.2.5p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p5) says it's static storage duration it outside a function or automatic storage duration.

Comment: @pmg, being an lvalue the address of a compound literal can be taken, but its lifetime is limited to the scope where it belongs. It has static storage duration if at file level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the both cases you are using compound literals.

In the first case in the declaration

```
LinkedList movies2 = {
    .head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
    .size=1
};
```

you are using the compound literal `(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL}` of the type `Node` in the initializer list the address of which is used as an initializer for the data member `head` of the structure `LinkedList`.

In the second case you at first created an object of the type `LimkedList`

```
LinkedList movies2;
```

and then you are using the assignment operator to the created object with the compound literal of the type `LinkedList`

```
(LinkedList) {
    .head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
    .size=1
}
```

that is

```
movies2 = (LinkedList) {
    .head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
    .size=1
};
```

That is there are no any casting. There are used two different compound literals. One of the type Node and other of the type LinkedList.

To make it clear. Consider a simple example

```
int x = { 10 };
```

in the declaration above the variable `x` is initialized by the integer constant 10.

You can write also the following way

```
int tmp = { 10 };
int x;
x = tmp;
```

Here there is created an intermediate variable to initialize the variable `x`.  A compound literal in fact is an unnamed object. The code above may be rewritten like

```
int x;
x = ( int ){ 10 };
```

Here there is no any casting. This expression  `( int ){ 10 }` creates an unnamed object of the type `int` that is initialized by the integer constant  10. And this newly created unnamed object is assigned to the variable `x`.

See also the following question [What are the advantages of using “{}” for casting in C Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504212/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-for-casting-in-c-language/66504269#66504269)

Comment: right, but why would `{.head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL}, .size=1};` fail (without the explicit cast)?

Comment: @David542 There is no any casting. There are used two different compound literals.

Answer (score 1):

What appears to be an *explicit cast* is part of the compound literal semathics `(type_name){ }`.

The syntax of a compound literal can be confused with a typecast, however a cast is a non-lvalue expression whereas a compound literal is an lvalue.

C11 N1570 [**§6.5.2.5**](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)

> #### Semantics
>
> 3. A postfix expression that **consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers** is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.

The first one is an initializer, not an assignment, so doesn't need it.

---

I would also note that in the expression `.head = &(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL}` the compound literal being an lvalue, can be taken by address, but its lifetime is limited to the scope where it belongs, accessing it outside that scope invokes undefined behavior, ***i.e.***:

```
LinkedList getLinkedList()
{
    LinkedList movies2;
    movies2 = (LinkedList){
        .head = &(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
        .size = 1};       
    return movies2;
}
```

```
LinkedList l = getLinkedList();
printf("%s", l.head->item.title); // undefined behavior
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it `typecast`

Comment: @EugeneSh., well yes, but what should I call it, a  a parenthesized type name ? :)

Comment: "The `(type_name)` you are referring in the question as "explicit cast (which it is not)"` :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have covered the difference between initialization and assignment from a compound literal.  There's another conceptual point that needs to be brought up however:

```
LinkedList movies2 = {
    .head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
    .size=1
};
```

In *either* case, you're creating a linked list and setting the head to point to a node that is not dynamically allocated nor part of some application defined pool.  Members of a linked list are typically either created dynamically via `malloc` or taken from a pool.

What you have now is one node of the list that is "special" in that it hasn't been added to the list the way other nodes would have been added, meaning you would need extra logic to keep track of it and handle it differently from other nodes in the list if it were removed.

It would be better to initialize the head of the list to `NULL`.  Then your add / delete functions would need to know whether or not the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Be cause in the first snippet you are initializing your struct with those values.
But in your second snippet you are creating a [compound literal](https://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404) and then copying it to your struct.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the l-value and r-value are expected to be of same type. In the expression

```
movies2 = (LinkedList) {
.head=&(Node){{"Avatar", 2010}, NULL},
.size=1 };
```

you are making sure the r-value is of type LinkedList. If you drop (LinkedList), the r-value's type is not known. That's the reason for the error.